# Flask-Jinja2 - how to iterate on many-to-many relationship

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, jinja2

I'm building a forum system for a course assignment where every post can have up to 5 tags. Posts and tags are stored in separate tables with a tags_post intermediate table linking them. The code looks like so:

```
class Post(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'Post'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable = False)
    content = db.Column(db.String(5000), nullable = False)
    date = db.Column(db.DateTime, 
                      nullable = False,
                      default = datetime.utcnow)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer,
                        ForeignKey('User.id'),
                        nullable = False)

class Tag(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'Tag'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable = False)

class Tags_Post(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'Tags_Post'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    tag_id = db.Column(db.Integer, 
                            ForeignKey('Tag.id'), 
                            nullable = False)
    post_id = db.Column(db.Integer,
                        ForeignKey('Post.id'),
                        nullable = False)
```

All of this is injected via a context processor like so:

```
@app.context_processor
def inject_data():
    posts = db.session.query(Post).all()
    tags = db.session.query(Etiqueta).all()
    post_tags = db.session.query(Etiquetas_Post).all()

    return dict (
        posts = posts,
        tags = tags,
        post_tags = post_tags,
    )
```

When attempting to render a post's list of tags into HTML, this is the best that came to my mind.

```
{% for post in posts}
 {% for post_tag in post_tags %}
   {% if post_tag.post_id == post.id %}
     {% for tag in tags %}
       {% if tag.id == post_tag.tag_id %}
         <p>{{tag.name}}</p>
       {% endif %}
     {% endfor %}
   {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

... Which works and is in line with what we've been taught so far, but is generally horrendous. What's a better way to go about this?

Comment: I'd suggest using the SQLAlchemy relationship features to link your database elements in the correct structure.  Then you'd only need to load the posts, with tags and post_tags coming along with each post.

Comment: Please refer to the many to many relationship here: https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/models/